# vcf files modification before converting to BCF

Tags: bioinformatics, bcftools, vcf-variant-call-format

I am adding new vcf files to a previously made bcf file in which the ID field in the VCF had been set to `CHR:POS:POS:REF:ALT` ?

How do I set the ID field in the VCF to `CHR:POS:POS:REF:ALT` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `--set-id` option.  From the documentation at http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html:

To assign the ID:

```
bcftools annotate --set-id +'%CHROM\_%POS\_%REF\_%FIRST_ALT' file.vcf
```